# @Mock and @InjectMock use cases

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Does @Mock and @InjectMock create a new mock value for every test in my test class ? Wondering how this works and if it doesn't create a new mock value do I have to use reset ?

Answer (score 2):

```
@Mock is shorthand for Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
```

You use this to initialize a mock.

```
@InjectMocks is shorthand for MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
```

You use this to set initialize your class with all of the mocks you created!

#### EXAMPLE TEST SETUP

This will give you a clean setup for every test (@Test) you write.

```
public class FooTest {
    private Foo foo = new Foo();

    @Mock
    private Bar bar;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetupOk() { // delete this test once it passes
        assertNotNull(foo);
        assertNotNull(bar); // this will fail if you remove @Mock
    }
}
```

---

You use these annotations together to properly setup the class under test.

Note that you still have to configure your mocks to return the desired behavior! (see Mockito.when in the **[API documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html)**).

Answer (score 1):

According to [`MockitoJUnitRunner`'s documentation](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html):

> Mocks are initialized before each test method.